# Automatic Macro in Access to check today date minus date on table

Tags: ms-access, macros, vba

Is there a an automatic way to do this scenrio in access?

I have a table which have StartDate, EndDate and checkerBox

what my goal is like today is January 31, I want a VBA or Macro something in access to check if the EndDate=Today it should Check the CheckBox if not leave it like that...

I'm looking a good way to do this... any suggestion is welcome

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this in vba :

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

  If DateDiff("d", inputEndDate, Date) = 0 Then
   chkDate = 1  ' Check the checkbox chkDate
  End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the "checkerBox" in your table is a Yes/No field and you want to update the value of that field then this might be what you're after:

```
UPDATE [TableName] SET [checkerBox]=True WHERE [EndDate]=Date()
```